# Should I use angular-seed or yeoman for a new Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm a little confused about which way I should create a new AngularJS application. As far as I can tell there seems to be a couple of ways to do it, either using angular-seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

or

yeoman - http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

What I can't find is any resources on why you would choose one method over the other. The resulting directory structures look quite different to me. Is it correct to say that one of the main differences is that angular-seed doesn't use Bower or Grunt out of the box, whereas a yeoman generated application does?

If I used angular-seed and wanted to add grunt to it then I am guessing this would be a bit of a manual process?

Answer (score 14):

Definitely use Yeoman.  It gives you more than just a project structure out of the box (it has tasks for tests and building all ready to go).  However, it's debatable which yeoman generator to use. It really depends on the project. I would suggest one of these:

**Simple Project:** https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

**Large Project:** https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular

Answer (score 9):

Well, I realize this questions's a bit old, but for a June, 2015 perspective, I had lots of problems with generator-angular, following along with the http://yeoman.io/codelab.html tutorial.  Bootstrap wasn't included correctly for the non-Sass path suggested.  (I entered the issue in Github -- workaround  is not to use SASS -- but then you'll need Ruby + Compass).  Also the unit tests lesson tripped me up due to karma errors and I spent quite a bit of time getting that straightened out.  So it's fair to say I lost the better part of a weekend to generator-angular / yo problems.  So I'd be inclined to lean toward other solutions, or just build the app out from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to look at https://github.com/kburson/ng-cafe/wiki/ng-Boilerplate,-WTF%3F

https://plus.google.com/+JoshDavidMiller/posts/atmw35S29Zs

I find ng-boilerplate pretty clean and more in control. yeoman feels like too many things happening behind black boxes

Answer (score 3):

Generaly, angular-seed isn't recommended for big angular projects because of it's monolithic file organisation (1 file for controllers, 1 for directives, ...), but for small projects it's ok.

With yeoman, you have multiple ways to create an angular application, as there are multiple angular generators (see here http://yeoman.io/community-generators.html), so maybe one of these will suit you.

Of course you can add grunt (and bower) later in any project, but you have to create your own gruntfile.

I think it is a good idea to start with a bare folder (but good structure) and add the tools when you feel you need them.